# Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faYoutube'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, font-awesome

I'm using  "next": "13.3.1" after successfully install @fortawesome 6.4.0 unable to set social icons.

[image: ERROR! ScreenShort]

How to resolve

Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faYoutube'